# Wordpress - Update post by meta information

Tags: php, database, wordpress, post

I'm looking for a solution, where I can update posts by meta information and not by id.

I got my content from an external resource via jsonp. I save the content into the database.

The only way I have found is, to update a post by id - but I have no id. What I have, is an article ID from the other resource. I save this article id to every wp post as meta information.

So, is there any way, to update a post by it's meta information?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post relevant code so that people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
here is some code and what I have done right now:

```
public function saveArticleInWpDatabase($json_data){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($json_data); $i++) {

        $articleId = $json_data[$i]['articleId'];
        $img = $json_data[$i]['img'];

        $articleHeadline = $json_data[$i]['articleContent']['headline'];
        $articleContent = $json_data[$i]['articleContent']['content'];

        $termsInput = $json_data[$i]['articleContent']['terms'];
        $terms = explode(',',$termsInput);
        $creationDate = $json_data[$i]['articleCreationDate'];
        $modifiedDate = $json_data[$i]['articleModifiedDate'];

    //Check if post with article ID in postmeta exists
        $existingId = $this->wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_id FROM ".$this->wpdb->postmeta." WHERE (meta_key = 'article_id' AND meta_value = '".$articleId."')");

        //Posts doesn't exist
        if ($existingId == null) {

            $my_post = array(
                'post_date' => $creationDate,
                'post_modified' => $modifiedDate,
                'post_title' => $articleHeadline,
                'post_content' => $articleContent,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_category' => array(0, $categoryId)
            );

            $last_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);

            add_post_meta($last_id, 'article_id', $articleId, true);
            wp_set_post_categories($last_id, array(0,$categoryId), true);
            wp_set_post_terms( $last_id,$terms, 'post_tag', true );

            //$this->_import_photo($last_id, $img);
        }
        //Post exists
        else{
            $my_post = array(
                'ID' => $existingId,
                'post_date' => $creationDate,
                'post_modified' => $modifiedDate,
                'post_title' => $articleHeadline,
                'post_content' => $articleContent,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_category' => array(0, $categoryId)
            );

            //Get last modified date and compare it with the new one
            $lastUpdate = $this->wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_modified FROM " . $this->wpdb->posts . " WHERE ID = ".$existingId);

            if(strcmp($lastUpdate, $modifiedDate) != 0){
                var_dump("Update article with id: " . $existingId);
                $last_id = wp_update_post($my_post);
            }
            else{
                var_dump("Article: " . $existingId . " Nothing changed");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I save the unique article number from the other CMS if the article doesn't exists.

If the article with the meta_key: article_id and the current value exist, I check if the modified date is the same or not. If not, I will update the posts.

I call this function via a unix cron job every minute. But I think, that this is not the best way (performance)(too many db requests?).

The other think is, that the post_modified value is always the same as post_date, but I got two different values in my json.

e.g.

```
"articleCreationDate": "2012-05-21 14:38:29", "articleModifiedDate": "2016-02-11 14:52:01"
```

But it only saved the articleCreationDate in both columns(post_date, post_modified).

So, did anyone has a better solution or idea? And did anyone know, why it doesn't save the modified date value from my json?

Cheers